# Create and Read List<> from cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I'm trying to display recently viewed products and so far I have already done that. I have a `Product` table that has many products stored. I have `HomeController` which has an Action method of `Details()` that display product details.

I have wrote `AddRecentProduct` method which stores Recently Viewed Products (10) in the `Session`

Now I want to store these recent viewed product list into cookies for atleast 30days on visitors computer, because session expires. Just like Imdb Recently Viewed.

Also If I create another table in my database `RecentlyViewed` with columns `rv_id, userId, productId` how will I save recentlyViewedList data in this ? The userId column will hold loggedIn user's id but what if a user is a Guest (not registered) what's the solution then ? Do I need to use GUID then ?

**RecentProduct.cs**

```
public class RecentProduct
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProdutName { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastVisited { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public void AddRecentProduct(List<RecentProduct> list, int id, string name, int maxItems)
    {
        var item = recentProductList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ProductId == id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            list.Add(new RecentProduct
            {
                ProductId = id,
                ProdutName = name,
                LastVisited = DateTime.Now,
            });
        }
        while (list.Count > maxItems)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var list = Session["RecentProductList"] as List<RecentProduct>;
        if (list == null)
        {
            list = new List<RecentProduct>();
            Session["RecentProductList"] = list;
        }
        AddRecentProduct(list, id.Value, product.Name, 10);
        ViewData["RecentProductList"] = list;
        return View(product);
    }
```

**ProductDetails View Page**

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
            @{
                var recentProductList = ViewData["RecentProductList"] as List<Project.Models.RecentProduct>;
            }

            @foreach (var recentProduct in recentProductList)
            {
                <p>@recentProduct.ProdutName (id: @recentProduct.ProductId)        </p>
            }
        </div>
```

I am getting the desired result with session, Now I want to do this same with cookies.

**This is what I'm trying** Creating cookie:

```
List<RecentProduct> yourList = new List<RecentProduct>();
        RecentProduct rc = new RecentProduct();
        rc.ProdutName = product.Name;
        rc.ProductId = product.ProductId;
        rc.ImageUrl = product.ImagePath;
        rc.LastVisited = DateTime.Now;
        yourList.Add(rc);

        var yourListString = String.Join(",", yourList);
        // Create a cookie
        HttpCookie yourListCookie = new HttpCookie("YourList", yourListString);

        // The cookie will exist for 7 days
        yourListCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);

        // Write the Cookie to your Response
        Response.Cookies.Add(yourListCookie);
```

and In **ProductDetails View Page** reading cookies like this:

```
 @if (Request.Cookies["YourList"] != null)
    {
        // Your cookie exists - grab your value and create your List
        List<string> yourList = Request.Cookies["YourList"].Value.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToString(x)).ToList();

        // Use your list here
        <p>@yourList</p>

    }
```

I'm not getting any result. How can I read cookie and values ?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for you is using Html5 Web Storage.
 it lets you store up to 5mb in local browser. 
 you can only read and write via javascript.
example:

```
    $('#btnLocalStorage').click(function()  
{  
    var txtName = $("#txtName").val();  
    //set item  
    localStorage.setItem("EmpName", txtName);  
});  

$('#btnLocalStorageRemove').click(function()  
 {  
    //remove item  
    localStorage.removeItem("EmpName");  
});  
$('#btnLocalStorageClear').click(function()   
 {  
    //clear Local Storage  
    localStorage.clear();  
});  
$('#btnLocalStorageLength').click(function()   
 {  
    var localStoragelength = localStorage.length;  
    alert("The length of Local storage is " + localStoragelength);  

});
```

By the way it has no expire time and u dont need guid.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cookies, why do you need RecentlyViewed table then? Storing recent product ids in cookie will work for both logged-in and anonymous user.

Comment: Please read the question again. Right now I am storing it in `Session` and I want to store it in Cookies as list of products and I said **IF** I create a table for storing recently viewed products that what would be the solution.